# Fedora update fails for "filesystem" package

Tags: yum, packages

I have Fedora 19 currently installed and the filesystem package has shown up in the updates. I find it a little peculiar on how to actually update the filesystem package.

> Running transaction Updating : filesystem-3.2-13.fc19.x86_64 1/2
>
> Error unpacking rpm package filesystem-3.2-13.fc19.x86_64  error:
>
> unpacking of archive **failed on file /lib: cpio: rename**
>
> filesystem-3.1-2.fc18.x86_64 was supposed to be removed but is not!
>
> Verifying : filesystem-3.1-2.fc18.x86_64 1/2 Verifying :
>
> filesystem-3.2-13.fc19.x86_64 2/2 Failed: filesystem.x86_64
> 0:3.1-2.fc18 filesystem.x86_64 0:3.2-13.fc19 Complete!

Comment: you could try to download the package manually. Also you could try the following # yum clean all and # yum update

Comment: And what is the output of: `ls -ld /lib`?

Comment: $ ls -ld /lib
drwxr-xr-x. 12 root root 4096 Jul 27 18:41 /lib

Comment: You could run `strace -f yum update -y filesystem >log 2>&1`, and see what the failing rename syscall is.  I.e.: what the target name is, and what the error code is.  (If it's EPERM, remember it could be some selinux damage - check the audit log).

Comment: How did you get your system into this state? Did you upgrade it from something?

Comment: ran strace, was an EPERM problem renaming the /lib symlink back to /lib. Disabled selinux, still same issue. Rerunning fedup-cli to reinstall F19

Comment: Did not work, going to now re-install entire system from media

Comment: This trouble has relation to immutable attribute but I still do not know how to deal with it

Answer (score 0):

I reformatted the root partition and re-installed the base system. Was able to walk through the update from F18* -> F19 (F = Fedora).

*Issues with NIC drivers were resolved in upgrade to F19.